# How does Castle Windsor work? Does it wrap all objects that are registered?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Does castle windsor basically create a list of all registered objects, and then wrap them with their own implementation which basically autowires the properties with objects that were registered with windsor already?

Curious, Does this make decompiling a little trickier to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Windsor doesn't do that, and in fact no IoC container I know does that. Containers usually use reflection and configuration (either conventions or explicit configuration) to autowire registered components.

Many containers offer integration with proxy libraries, which can wrap a component, but that's an orthogonal topic, unrelated to container autowiring.

Comment: And to add to that, anything that an IoC container (with the notable exception of PostSharp, if you consider that an IoC container) would do would be at runtime, and would not affect the compiled code at all. Thus it would not affect decompiling in any significant way.